# WCF Service on local network with Dynamic IP Address

Tags: wcf

I'm a newbie to WCF.

I learnt that in order to address a WCF Service in my local network server, I have to set a baseAddress to the IP Address of my local server.

But what happens if my Internet Service Provider works on a Dynamic IP approach, as I understand it all IP Addresses of my local network machines can change over time, what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Do you know the hostname name of the server.  The server name should be converted to it's IP address by the DNS if you are on the same network.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm a newbie to it. You mean the hostname of my ISP server?, how can I know it? How can I convert it to it's IP Address? And how does it help me?

Comment: Your base address is currently something in the format of: `http://127.0.0.1:8734/Myservice`.  You could try `http://Domain.MyLocalServerName:8734/Myservice` the networks DNS server should resolve the request to `Domain.MyLocalServerName` into the current IP address.

Comment: How can I find my exact case of "Domain.MyLocalServerName:8734"?

Comment: [Get Hostname from IP address](http://serverfault.com/questions/88064/how-to-determine-the-hostname-from-an-ip-address-in-a-windows-network)

Comment: Please, answer the question to check it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base address is currently something in the format of: `http://127.0.0.1:8734/Myservice`.

You could try `http://Domain.MyLocalServerName:8734/Myservice` the networks DNS server should resolve the request to `Domain.MyLocalServerName` into the current IP address.

Link to [Get a Hostname from IP Address](https://serverfault.com/questions/88064/how-to-determine-the-hostname-from-an-ip-address-in-a-windows-network).