# WCF config for server with dynamic IP address

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have created a WCF service which is hosted in a Windows service and tested it locally and all seems to now work fine.

I am now ready to deploy on to a local server in the same domain but the server has a dynamic IP address.

What do I need to set as the base address, if it needs to change, and how do I call this service as it has a dynamic IP?

I had a look here [WCF Service on local network with Dynamic IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577422/wcf-service-on-local-network-with-dynamic-ip-address) which is probably the same issue but it didn't help me.

current base address in config file is this

```
<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service" />
```

For argument sake lets say the computer name is 'ServerPC' and Domain is 'MyDomain.net'

I have tried `http://MyDomain.net.ServerPC:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service` and `http://ServerPC:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service` but I just got the following error.

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://MyDomain.net.ServerPC:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://MyDomain.net.ServerPC:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://MyDomain.net.ServerPC:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service'.    There was no endpoint listening at http://MyDomain.net.ServerPC:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.    The remote name could not be resolved: 'MyDomain.net.ServerPC'HTTP GET Error    URI: http://MyDomain.net.ServerPC:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service    There was an error downloading 'http://MyDomain.net.ServerPC:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service'.    The remote name could not be resolved: 'MyDomain.net.ServerPC'

UPDATE
Issue is resolved. Administrator informed me that a rule was added to the firewall for the port but when I check it wasn't.
Also, the address I used to call was `http://PCNAME:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service`. Obvisouly substituate PCNAME with the PC name. Did not required domain name in the call.

Comment: Why don't you use domain name ;; DNS will do the rest

Comment: I did? `http://MyDomain.net.ServerPC.........` Thats what generated the error